# Spark sql execution plan analysis giving empty results

Tags: apache-spark

I am new to spark and i've been playing around with some simple sql queries to understand how it works.

When i go to the query explanation page, I can see that after it loads the data (parquet), there's a filter stage which gives 0 outputs. Is that normal? Is it really 0 output tuples?
[image: Plan]

Edit: The query is:

`select store.s_store_sk
from store join customer_address on (store.s_zip = customer_address.ca_zip)
where substr(ca_zip, 1, 5) <> substr(s_zip, 1, 5)`:

i am using this dataset : http://www.tpc.org/tpc_documents_current_versions/pdf/tpc-ds_v2.3.0.pdf
Table info for "store" at the bottom of page 24 and "customer_address" at the bottom of page 27.

Comment: what is your filter condition ? Shoud query return results after filtering the rows?

Comment: The query is a simple inequality join. The final output tuples should be around 600, certainly not 0

Comment: I can only guess until I see the real query. It is normal to filter out all the records in a sql join. That is totally dependent on the data and the equality of the fields you are joining the tables with.

Comment: I've updated the question. Sorry i should have posted query info at first

Comment: There is nothing wrong here. Please check the row count by only executing part of the query (remove where condition at first and see if its gives results) If it happens, The last condition you've given doesn't exist in the data and hence, no results. If it doesn't give results, there is something wrong with the field s_zip and ca_zip tables that you've used for joining the two tables. Its more of a logical verification.